# cpufreq directory not present. How to change governor for P states in such a case

Tags: linux, kernel, electrical-power

One node in my cluster is using ondemand governor which is specified in the directory:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor ..
```

`Scaling_governor` allows us to choose the governor of our choice.

But this sub-directory is absent in the other node of the cluster.

How do I change the governor for `Pstates` in such case ?

Answer (score 3):

Verify in your BIOS that you have something akin to "OS level power management" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

We have to recompile the kernel in this case after choosing acpi Pstates driver in menuconfig